# Why is my recursive prolog script not working?

Tags: prolog

Can anyone help me out with Prolog recursive functions?

I have to type in a recursive input and it should give me true, but it gives me an error and I sitll don´t know how to figure it out

```
Bob(Food(X)):- Bob(X).
Bob(eat(X)):- Bob(X).
Bob(yummy(X)).
```

Is what I have and Input Food(Food(eat(yummy)))should result in true

But I get an Error: Unknown procedure: Food/1 (DWIM could not correct goal)
this is basically the whole story.

Comment: Your program does not mention any `Food` predicate. Furthermore predicates start with a lowercase, so `bob`, not `Bob`...

Comment: The last clause should also be `yummy`.

Comment: Apoligies.Everything is written small :D, but how would I define the Food predicate properly?

Comment: So instea of bob(yummy(X)). bob(yummy) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

predicates, functors and constants start with a lowercase. Your `yummy` is also a constant, so there is no `(X)` part here. The predicate should thus look like:

```
bob(yummy).
bob(food(X)):-
    bob(X).
bob(eat(X)):-
    bob(X).
```

This then gives us a:

```
?- bob(food(food(eat(yummy)))).
true.
```

Comment: Ok well. I edited it and I am getting a false for a reason?. I double checked if the code is the same, but for some reason I still get false.

Comment: @NintyNinerQuery you did call it with `bob(...)` right? You did also use identifiers that start with a *lowercase*, so `food` instead of `Food`, `

Comment: bob(yummy).
bob(food(X)):- bob(X).                                                                                  
bob(eat(X)):- bob(X).

Comment: `(eat(X)):- bob(X)` makes no sense, you need something before the `(eat(...`.

Comment: @NintyNinerQuery: how do you *call* the predicate? What is the query you use.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this site :D, I ment to write bob(eat(X)):- bob(X)

Comment: bob(food(food(eat(yummy)))). that´s the input I use

Comment: @NintyNinerQuery: you did reload the file in the interpreter, right?

Comment: Yup. Can confirm I saved and then reloaded everything. :(

Comment: @NintyNinerQuery: well on swish it seems to work: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/testbob.pl

Comment: Appologies. I got it to work. I thank you very, very much for your time and effort! I wrote "fod" instead of "food" in the code...